# Singleton class inheritance

Tags: c#, .net

I have declared a singleton class with protected constructor and derived in other classes.So is derived classes instance can be singleton or not.

Is there is way to keep derived classes also singleton?

Comment: why will you do that?

Comment: It's possible until your class is not `sealed`

Comment: It's up to the developer who creates/uses the derived class.  If you really don't trust them, then don't allow them to inherit from your class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a listing of good thread-safe singleton class i use:

```
namespace Helpers.DesignPatterns
{
public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private static volatile T _instance;
    private static object _syncRoot = new Object();

    protected Singleton()
    {
    }

    private static T CreateInstance()
    {
        ConstructorInfo cInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new Type[0],
            new ParameterModifier[0]);

        return (T)cInfo.Invoke(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Точка входа синглтона
    /// </summary>
    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = CreateInstance();
                }
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

It's extremly simple to create derieved class:

`class CredentialsManager : Singleton<CredentialsManager>`

But usually it is not a very good solution to have more than 1 singleton class in project. I have 4 in mine :)

Comment: +раз for the motherland

Answer (score 0):

Usually Singleton classes are sealed (will prevent inheritance) so derived classes will not ruin the Singleton.

But If you have to derive from the class, then the derived class can **choose** to be implemented as a Singleton. But you can't enforce it only using the inheritance process alone.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on implementation. Singletons usually have private constructor and possibly marked sealed, if the singleton class has a private constructor, you won't be able to inherit it. If it is at least protected you can. If you just inherit from singleton class, result will not be singleton so you should follow the pattern and make it also singleton.